# z-index issue with overlay not able to click

Tags: html, css

up I am able to add the scroll to the pop up if it is bigger than the screen but I am having issue with the overlay I am not able to click on it..if you double click on overlay you will notice the cross button get the selection but the at the bottom left side powered by should get the selection

```
.booklyng-modal-body .popup-box-wrapper {
     overflow-x: hidden !important;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
     z-index:222; 
}
```

This code is to add the scroll for my div kindly check the following link
if you can help [click here](http://demo.richestsoft.com/zfb/Popup.html)

Comment: Can you please provide a working example of this

Comment: @Anshul   have added a link this is a working example. it's pure css currently.

Comment: Please include a [MCVE] in the question itself. Context is important. What is the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` property only works on positioned elements. So try adding `position: relative;` to your selector.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Your answer is somewhat misleading. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position re a "positioned" element and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index for a better CSS reference.

Answer (score 0):

For adding z-index on specific part or div, you have to clarify the z-index of overlay area.For eg. if you want to add z-index for image card over parent div then you have to add z-index:-1 for parent div and for child element z-index:1;